# Visual C#: Cannot use the Convert method in winforms anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Maybe I am missing something entirely simple here, but in any new windows form I create, I can no longer use the Convert method. I am pretty sure all my using directives are there and I am using no extensions. I have done nothing to change VS since the last time I used it, when everything worked.

Could it be a hiccup of VS 2011 Beta or just a simple error on my part?

Here is my code along with the error displayed:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for
>   'ToInt32'
>
> and no extension method 'ToInt32' accepting a first argument of type
>
> 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' could be found
>
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TempConvert
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int degreesEntered;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            degreesEntered = Convert.ToInt32(Degrees.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is you have a button named `Convert` which is hiding the static class - you can try using the full namespace to reference it, or doing an `int.Parse`

```
System.Convert.ToInt32(Degrees.Text);
```

Comment: Simple oversight on my part. Thank you for the quick, and understanding, response. It did not click (No pun intended) that I had named my button with a reserved keyword.

Comment: "Convert" isn't a keyword. This problem could happen with any class, and is essentially the point of namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int32.Parse()` when parsing text into integers.

Answer (score 1):

Your button `Convert` should be renamed as it has the same name of the class [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) and you might be using this class in several other parts of the application

Answer (score 0):

Use fully qualified name as `System.Convert`